# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space gradle compiling android

Tags: java, android, gradle

i was compiling an android app with gradle in my VPS and i got this error:

```
Running gradle assembleRelease
on builds/2014428_12146137
Note: in order to honour the org.gradle.jvmargs and/or org.gradle.java.home values specified for this build, it is necessary to fork a new JVM.
To avoid the slowdown associated with this extra process, you might want to consider running Gradle with the daemon enabled.
Please see the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.798 secs

{ [Error: Command failed: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$DgmMethodRecord.loadDgmInfo(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:155)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:61)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:126)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)

FAILURE: Build aborted because of an internal error.

* What went wrong:
Build aborted because of an unexpected internal error. Please file an issue at: http://forums.gradle.org.

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get additional debug info.

* Exception is:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.gradle.util.MutableURLClassLoader.invokeMethod() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, [Ljava.lang.Object;) values: [defineClass, [org.gradle.initialization.SettingsScript_Decorated, ...]]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.AsmBackedEmptyScriptGenerator.generateEmptyScriptClass(AsmBackedEmptyScriptGenerator.java:80)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.AsmBackedEmptyScriptGenerator.generate(AsmBackedEmptyScriptGenerator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.loadFromDir(DefaultScriptCompilationHandler.java:167)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.compile(FileCacheBackedScriptClassCompiler.java:58)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.ShortCircuitEmptyScriptCompiler.compile(ShortCircuitEmptyScriptCompiler.java:35)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.CachingScriptClassCompiler.compile(CachingScriptClassCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScriptCompilerFactory$ScriptCompilerImpl.compile(DefaultScriptCompilerFactory.java:60)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:114)
    at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.applySettingsScript(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.initialization.ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.process(ScriptEvaluatingSettingsProcessor.java:59)
    at org.gradle.initialization.PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.process(PropertiesLoadingSettingsProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.loadSettings(SettingsHandler.java:101)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.findSettingsAndLoadIfAppropriate(SettingsHandler.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.SettingsHandler.findAndLoadSettings(SettingsHandler.java:45)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:126)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

I have in gradle.properties this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
```

and in gradlew this:

```
# For Darwin, add options to specify how the application appears in the dock
if $darwin; then
GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS \"-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME\" \"-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns\" \"-Xmx1024m\" \"-Xms256m\" \"-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m\""
fi
```

I dont know why crash..help.

EDIT: (I am root, i dont know if this affect..)

with --debug

```
Running gradle assembleRelease --debug
on builds/2014428_122049683
12:21:07.621 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer] Finished configuring with level: DEBUG, configurers: [org.gradle.logging.internal.OutputEventRenderer@2a2096d7, org.gradle.logging.internal.logback.LogbackLoggingConfigurer@418f12dc, org.gradle.logging.internal.JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer@181f4b24]
12:21:07.687 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.services.NativeServices] Native-platform is not available.
12:21:07.697 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.nativeplatform.services.NativeServices] Native-platform terminal is not available. Continuing with fallback.
12:21:08.726 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer] Finished configuring with level: DEBUG, configurers: [org.gradle.logging.internal.OutputEventRenderer@2a2096d7, org.gradle.logging.internal.logback.LogbackLoggingConfigurer@418f12dc, org.gradle.logging.internal.JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer@181f4b24]
12:21:08.727 [INFO] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Starting Build
12:21:08.728 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Gradle user home: /root/.gradle
12:21:08.728 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Current dir: /root/ci/cifirext/builds/2014428_122049683
12:21:08.729 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Settings file: null
12:21:08.730 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.BuildLogger] Build file: null
12:21:08.752 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.BuildSourceBuilder] Starting to build the build sources.
12:21:08.753 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.BuildSourceBuilder] Gradle source dir does not exist. We leave.
12:21:08.754 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found env project properties: []
12:21:08.755 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradlePropertiesLoader] Found system project properties: []
12:21:08.947 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.mvnsettings.DefaultLocalMavenRepositoryLocator] No local repository in Settings file defined. Using default path: /root/.m2/repository
12:21:09.307 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on buildscript class cache for settings file '/root/ci/cifirext/builds/2014428_122049683/settings.gradle' (/root/.gradle/caches/1.4/scripts/settings_1lm5jovqikr5c3t58051j823ue/SettingsScript/buildscript).
12:21:09.308 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
12:21:09.310 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache] Invalidating buildscript class cache for settings file '/root/ci/cifirext/builds/2014428_122049683/settings.gradle' (/root/.gradle/caches/1.4/scripts/settings_1lm5jovqikr5c3t58051j823ue/SettingsScript/buildscript) as it was not closed cleanly.
12:21:09.311 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on buildscript class cache for settings file '/root/ci/cifirext/builds/2014428_122049683/settings.gradle' (/root/.gradle/caches/1.4/scripts/settings_1lm5jovqikr5c3t58051j823ue/SettingsScript/buildscript).
12:21:09.312 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire exclusive lock on buildscript class cache for settings file '/root/ci/cifirext/builds/2014428_122049683/settings.gradle' (/root/.gradle/caches/1.4/scripts/settings_1lm5jovqikr5c3t58051j823ue/SettingsScript/buildscript).
12:21:09.313 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
12:21:09.314 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryCache] Invalidating buildscript class cache for settings file '/root/ci/cifirext/builds/2014428_122049683/settings.gradle' (/root/.gradle/caches/1.4/scripts/settings_1lm5jovqikr5c3t58051j823ue/SettingsScript/buildscript) as it was not closed cleanly.
12:21:09.319 [INFO] [org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler] Compiling settings file '/root/ci/cifirext/builds/2014428_122049683/settings.gradle' using BuildScriptClasspathScriptTransformer.
12:21:09.567 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptCompilationHandler] Timing: Writing script to cache at /root/.gradle/caches/1.4/scripts/settings_1lm5jovqikr5c3t58051j823ue/SettingsScript/buildscript/classes took: 0.251 secs
12:21:09.572 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on buildscript class cache for settings file '/root/ci/cifirext/builds/2014428_122049683/settings.gradle' (/root/.gradle/caches/1.4/scripts/settings_1lm5jovqikr5c3t58051j823ue/SettingsScript/buildscript).
12:21:09.573 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on buildscript class cache for settings file '/root/ci/cifirext/builds/2014428_122049683/settings.gradle' (/root/.gradle/caches/1.4/scripts/settings_1lm5jovqikr5c3t58051j823ue/SettingsScript/buildscript).
12:21:09.573 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
12:21:09.665 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
12:21:09.665 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
12:21:09.666 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
12:21:09.667 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 2.453 secs
12:21:09.670 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on buildscript class cache for settings file '/root/ci/cifirext/builds/2014428_122049683/settings.gradle' (/root/.gradle/caches/1.4/scripts/settings_1lm5jovqikr5c3t58051j823ue/SettingsScript/buildscript).
12:21:09.700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.logging.internal.DefaultLoggingConfigurer] Finished configuring with level: DEBUG, configurers: [org.gradle.logging.internal.OutputEventRenderer@2a2096d7, org.gradle.logging.internal.logback.LogbackLoggingConfigurer@418f12dc, org.gradle.logging.internal.JavaUtilLoggingConfigurer@181f4b24]

{ [Error: Command failed: 12:21:08.181 [ERROR] [system.err] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
12:21:08.183 [ERROR] [system.err]   at java.util.ArrayList.<init>(ArrayList.java:144)
12:21:08.184 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GeneratedMetaMethod$DgmMethodRecord.loadDgmInfo(GeneratedMetaMethod.java:193)
12:21:08.184 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:155)
12:21:08.186 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:83)
12:21:08.186 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:61)
12:21:08.187 [ERROR] [system.err]   at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:29)
12:21:08.187 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:100)
12:21:08.188 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.newInstance(ClassGeneratorBackedInstantiator.java:36)
12:21:08.188 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:126)
12:21:08.189 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:99)
12:21:08.189 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:46)
12:21:08.190 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:38)
12:21:08.190 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.execute(InProcessGradleLauncherActionExecuter.java:25)
12:21:08.191 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
12:21:08.192 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
12:21:08.192 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
12:21:08.193 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
12:21:08.193 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
12:21:08.194 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
12:21:08.194 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
12:21:08.195 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
12:21:08.195 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
12:21:08.196 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
12:21:08.196 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
12:21:08.196 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
12:21:08.197 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
12:21:08.198 [ERROR] [system.err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
12:21:08.198 [ERROR] [system.err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
12:21:08.199 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
12:21:08.199 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
12:21:08.200 [ERROR] [system.err]   at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
12:21:09.659 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
12:21:09.662 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build aborted because of an internal error.
12:21:09.662 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
12:21:09.663 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
12:21:09.663 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Build aborted because of an unexpected internal error. Please file an issue at: http://forums.gradle.org.
] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

Comment: Well, did you run it with `--debug`?

Comment: Yes i will copy the result in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using a older version of debian repositories, i updated the version to the last(1.11 at this moment) and now works fine..

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=744337 say that error in `libjarjar-java`.

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=745815 - it fixed. Just update packages.